# Can  "do a haircut" be used colloquially to mean "have a haircut"?

Tags: idioms

Can *do a haircut* be used colloquially to mean *have a haircut*?

Comment: For the record, you don't "do" or "have" or anything else a haircut, except "get" — you [**get** a haircut](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbAoXw_DqvM).

Comment: @Robusto I'm pretty sure that one can have a haircut - e.g. I might have a crewcut, and you might ask me what haircut I have.

Comment: @Marcin: Except the OP did not appear to be using it in that context.

Comment: @Robusto That does not make your general statement correct.

Comment: @Marcin: Who said it was a general statement? For the record, my comment implicitly narrows the scope of the question to time prior to and during the haircut process, and to future instances of discussing that process in the past tense. So you can go ahead and talk about "having" or "wearing" a mullet to your heart's content.

Comment: @Robusto I see no reason to infer any such narrowing. Your statement is given in general terms - "you don't "do" or "have" or anything else a haircut,".

Comment: @Marcin: My previous comment was intended as a codicil to make such narrowing explicit. If you want further words on the suggest, I am available in ELU chat.

Comment: @Robusto "If you want further words on the suggest," - I don't understand this as English. As to what you intend, that is of little relevance unless you express your intention.

Comment: @Marcin: Sorry, I meant to type "subject" but my fingers took over and typed something else. It happens. But as comment chains are not intended for tit-for-tat flame wars, perhaps we can move this to chat?

Comment: _Do_ has become an all-purpose verb these days, and I can't stand it.  "I'm going to do a short latte."  "We did Five Guys for lunch."  Ghastly.

Answer (score 3):

Doing implies an action performed. Having implies an action received. Doing a haircut implies that the haircut is something you will perform, a service you will give. Having a haircut implies that you will be receiving a haircut from another party.

Answer (score 0):

The difference this: "do a haircut" is just plain bad grammar.

It's probably common among youth and teenagers, but it's not correct English.

"Have a haircut" is the correct way of phrasing it.

Comment: It means it's still used?